# The Rollup CLI build is not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, rollup

So I'm trying to build a CLI tool, and I'm struggling with testing it. The build happens without any problems, but when I link it and execute the command, it throws this error.

I don't know much about Rollup or how the CLI and its execution work, so someone may be able to help, even with just a little bit.

Here is my rollup configs:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'
import shebang from 'rollup-plugin-add-shebang'

import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

export default {
    input: './index.ts',
    entry: './dist/clitool.js',
    plugins: [
        resolve(), 
        commonjs(), 
        typescript(), 
        terser(),
        builtins(),
        shebang()
    ],
    output: {
        file: './dist/clitool.js',
        format: 'es',
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        name: 'clitool'
    },
    watch: {
        chokidar: {},
        exclude: [
            'node_modules/**', 
            'dist/**'
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is my package:

```
{
  "name": "ikonik",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Ikonik is a CLI tool to generate icons for your projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --config .eslintrc.json && npx rollup -c",
    "dev": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --config .eslintrc.json  && npx rollup -c -w",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts --config .eslintrc.json",
    "cli": "npm run build && npm link"
  },
  "bin": {
    "ikonik": "./dist/ikonik.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.5",
    "@types/inquirer": "^9.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.0",
    "commander": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "inquirer": "^9.2.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "pretty-data": "^0.40.0",
    "rollup": "^4.10.0",
    "rollup-plugin-add-shebang": "^0.3.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "join": "^3.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "rollup-plugin-executable": "^1.6.3"
  }
}
```

What I do is simple: I run `npm run build, then I link it using` npm run link `. After that, I can use it globally. However, sometimes I encounter errors that include all the file details.

Here are the screenshots on what is showing:

1. [image]
2. [image]